# Random.Next() gives me the same value

Tags: c#, random

We have this class here:

```
public static class Helper
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    public static int GetRandomId()
    {
        return Random.Next(int.MinValue, 0);
    }
}
```

At some point calling `.GetRandomId` of `Helper` gives us the same integer - Why and how do avoid/fix this?

Note:
The field `Random` is a singleton-instance, and this behaviour does not occur in a loop (actually it doesn't even matter how much time there's between the calls).

To be even more specific:
At some point the random-machine returns only one value, regardless of the amount of calls! It's not about the likeliness, uniqueness ... - I think that I have (with this implementation) broken my random-instance ... how come?

Comment: If you really need unique ids, you should have look into GUIDs.

Comment: Please show us how you use it. That code `should` give you random values.

Comment: @chiffre no chance for that, we would have to adapt the whole db-scheme ... not an option - sry!

Comment: "Random" is not the same as "unique"

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: If you're trying to rely on `Random` to generate *unique* IDs, your schema is already broken. It would be better to fix it now than later... Why aren't you getting the database to generate the ID to start with? Please give more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet if you would just have digged deeper :) ... nope ... the problem is not, that i'm generating ids which are going to get stored. i'm generating id's which are used for temp-ui-actions, where i need negative (oh yes: to easily separate from the stored ids) ids ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: You still really haven't explained much about what you're doing... but why do you need it to be random at all? Why not use a counter?

Comment: @JonSkeet actually AndrewKennan has made this suggestion - i will go for this option!

Comment: you can have nums in sequence for the temp activity too :)

Comment: @V4Vendetta *can*, but not **must**

Comment: Indeed so true, that's the reason why SO exists :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Next method returns a pseudo-random number between int.MinValue and 0. It does not guarantee the numbers will be unique. What do you think happens if you call Random.Next(0,10) 11 times?

To prevent duplicates you'll need to keep track of which Ids have been issued.

Alternatively, is there any need for the Ids to be in a random order? Could you just use an incrementing int to generate Ids?

Comment: hey, the last one was a really good hint! " Could you just use an incrementing int to generate Ids?" - i think that will suffice ... actually this is *a* solution, but not the solution to the specific question ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: The specific question of why random numbers sometimes occur more than once is "because they do if they're random" - if you roll two dice, would you expect them to *always* be different?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, so... was the actual problem the "single instance of Random breaks when accessed from multiple threads" issue?

Comment: @AndrewKennan never heard of that :) ... could you please give me some more information?! another problem: i can not reproduce this on purpose (- this might be a nice indicator for a multi-threading issue)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, have a look at the Thread Safety section of Adam's link to Mr Skeet's excellent book.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: Ah, that wasn't *at all* clear from your question. Yes, as noted that's just a thread safety issue. Next time, please try to make your question clearer - read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: @JonSkeet ... we'll i'd rather say "even more clearer" ... actually "At some point calling .GetRandomId of Helper gives us the same integer" and the implementation should be clear enough ... but maybe we are just professsionally blinkered :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: "At some point calling .GetRandomId of Helper gives us the same integer" sounds like it's repeated *one value, once*. Not over and over again, which is entirely different. Your clarification after 20 minutes was *much* better, but that should have been in there from the start. Why do you think lots of people were trying to help you without seeing the real issue, but as soon as you *really* said what was going on, you got the answer to the underlying problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet aahhh ... now i get your *thinking* ... interesting, never looked at the question from this point! (btw, that's why i prefer talking over typing!)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is random, it doesn't remember what it has done in the past.

Keep a list of already given numbers and check it hasn't already been given before returning.

More details on why it also repeats more often than you would expect can be found here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: Just updated the answer to show that setting the seed to a tick count will help. The article linked to gives more information as well.

Comment: the default-ctor looks like this: `public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is always a chance it will generate the same number. Just keep a track of them so you don't repeat them, if that is what your use case requires.

Comment: It's because the seed is the same. Generate a new random instance to get a random number and they will change. Just been reading: http://www.functionx.com/csharp2/builtinclasses/random.htm